# Why does this projection matrix not work?

Tags: c, opengl, matrix, glsl

(Sorry for my english skills...)

I tryed to write my own shader with glsl #version 440 so I also use my own projection matrix but I only get this: [image: output]
instead of that [image]
(the second one is without the projection matrix)

Does anyone know the reason for what's happening ?

Matrix definition :

```
// projectionMatrix is global defined
void Perspective(float fovy, float aspect, float near, float far)
{
  fovy = degree*90;
  float f;
  f = 1/tan(fovy/2);

  projectionMatrix[0] = f/aspect;   projectionMatrix[4] = 0;    projectionMatrix[8] = 0;            projectionMatrix[12] = 0;
  projectionMatrix[1] = 0;      projectionMatrix[5] = f;    projectionMatrix[9] = 0;            projectionMatrix[13] = 0;
  projectionMatrix[2] = 0;      projectionMatrix[6] = 0;    projectionMatrix[10] = (far+near)/(near-far);   projectionMatrix[14] = (2*far*near)/near-far;
  projectionMatrix[3] = 0;      projectionMatrix[7] = 0;    projectionMatrix[11] = -1;          projectionMatrix[15] = 1;

  gl

UniformMatrix4fv(posProjectionMatrix, 1, GL_TRUE, projectionMatrix);
}
```

Vertex shader :

```
#version 440

in vec4 vertexPosition;
in vec4 vertexColor;

out vec4 Color;

uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;

void main() 
{
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix*vec4(vertexPosition.xyz, 1);
  Color = vertexColor;
}

//END
```

If you need more code, just ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of errors in your projection matrix:

```
projectionMatrix[14] = (2*far*near)/near-far;
```

There are parentheses missing in the expression, it should be:

```
projectionMatrix[14] = (2*far*near)/(near-far);
```

The last element is also wrong:

```
projectionMatrix[15] = 1;
```

This matrix element needs to be 0:

```
projectionMatrix[15] = 0.0f;
```

Also, as @Nicol Bolas already pointed out in a now deleted answer, you're building the matrix in column major order, so you should not use the argument to `glUniformMatrix4fv()` that transposes the matrix as part of the upload. The correct call is:

```
glUniformMatrix4fv(posProjectionMatrix, 1, GL_FALSE, projectionMatrix);
```